# Google direction time with traffic

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use google maps for my website, I want to get directions during traffic, how can I get estimated time during traffic in google maps directions?

I use the following code to get directions without traffic.

```
function direction(){
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();


    var nmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('direction-map'), mapOptions);
    directionsRenderer.setMap(nmap);

    calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {

    var blng = parseFloat($("#beginning-lng").val());
    var blat = parseFloat($("#beginning-lat").val());

    var dlng = parseFloat($("#destination-lng").val());
    var dlat = parseFloat($("#destination-lat").val());

    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(blat, blng);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(dlat, dlng);
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidTolls: true
    };
    directionsService.route(request,  function (result, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
            console.log(result);
            var distance = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
            var time = result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 60;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add driving options to request:

```
var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidTolls: true,
        drivingOptions: {
            departureTime: new Date(Date.now() + 10000),
            trafficModel: 'bestguess'
        }
    };
```

and get time in traffic from result:

```
var time = result.routes[0].legs[0].duration_in_traffic.value / 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get directions during traffic, see the documentation for  [DrivingOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DrivingOptions):

> **departureTime** (required for the drivingOptions object literal to be valid) specifies the desired time of departure as a Date object. The value must be set to the current time or some time in the future. It cannot be in the past. (The API converts all dates to UTC to ensure consistent handling across time zones.) For Google Maps Platform Premium Plan customers, if you include the departureTime in the request, the API returns the best route given the expected traffic conditions at the time, and includes the predicted time in traffic (duration_in_traffic) in the response. If you don't specify a departure time (that is, if the request does not include drivingOptions), the returned route is a generally good route without taking traffic conditions into account.
> **trafficModel** (optional) specifies the assumptions to use when calculating time in traffic. This setting affects the value returned in the duration_in_traffic field in the response, which contains the predicted time in traffic based on historical averages. Defaults to bestguess. The following values are permitted:
>
> - **bestguess** (default) indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be the best estimate of travel time given what is known about both historical traffic conditions and live traffic. Live traffic becomes more important the closer the departureTime is to now.
> - **pessimistic** indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be longer than the actual travel time on most days, though occasional days with particularly bad traffic conditions may exceed this value.
> - **optimistic** indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be shorter than the actual travel time on most days, though occasional days with particularly good traffic conditions may be faster than this value.

> Note: If departure time is not specified, choice of route and duration are based on road network and average time-independent traffic conditions. Results for a given request may vary over time due to changes in the road network, updated average traffic conditions, and the distributed nature of the service. Results may also vary between nearly-equivalent routes at any time or frequency.
> Note: To ensure that your request uses live traffic information, set the departureTime to now. Requests using traffic information are billed at a higher rate. Learn more about how Google Maps Platform products are billed.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y4wj6g8o/1/)

based off the request in the documentation and the samples in the documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    },
  });

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById("sidebar"));
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);

}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  directionsService
    .route({
      origin: 'Anaheim, CA',
      destination: 'Los Angeles, CA',
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      drivingOptions: {
        departureTime: new Date(Date.now() + 10000), // for the time 10000 milliseconds from now.
        trafficModel: 'optimistic'
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
    })
    .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status));
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar {
  flex-basis: 15rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 30rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

#sidebar {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar>div {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Directions Service</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```